# Remove selection when clicking on another list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping an array of objects as shown below

```
<div>
  {categoryArray.map(category => <DFCard  category={category} key={category.id}/>)}
</div>
```

**DFCard**

```
      <div className="cat_div" id={category.id} onClick={() => this.selectCategory(category.id)}>
          <i className={`${category.icon} fontawesome vertical_center setting_icon`}/>
          <span className="cat_lbl vertical_center">{category.name}</span>
          {this.state.selectedId === category.id && 'selected'}
      </div>


     selectCategory(id) {
        this.setState({
          selectedId: id
        })
    }
```

I'm trying to show a `selected` on the item i'm clicking on. My approach does not make the `selected` label to remove when clicking on another list item. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: You need to have a `selected` in your parent's state, not in DFCard

Comment: @UtsavPatel Thanks.Got it to working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 selectCategory(id) {
          let oldSelected = this.setState.selectedId;
          oldSelected.push(id)
          this.setState({selectedId: oldSelected})
    }

{this.state.selectedId && this.state.selectedId.indexOf(category.id) > -1  && 'selected'}
```